# WordPress: How to add compatibility (301 redirects) for old slugs of pages?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

When a slug for a post is updated, WordPress saves the old slug in the post_meta table. 
Having that, the old slug is still accessible and will result in a redirect to the new slug.

I want the same functionality for pages. Sometimes I want to change a slug. 
But when I change the slug for a page, the old slug won't be saved.

This result in 404's...

Does somebody know an easy way to fix this? Without changing pages into posts..

A plugin with this feature is also welcome! But I haven't found it yet. 
Only plugins that offer the functionality to create manual redirects..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to use 301 redirect plugin.For redirect from old slug to new slug.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Great, its nice plugin for 301 redirect.